# xsd <any/> different result in marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body xml:lang="en"><div></div></body>
</note>
```

The XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd">
    </xs:import>
    <xs:element name="note">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="body">
                    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xs:complexContent>
                            <xs:extension base="someType">
                                <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="required">
                                </xs:attribute>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:complexContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="someType" mixed="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" processContents="skip"/>
        </xs:sequence>  
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Checked [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) and it works.
But this does not work in Marklogic, the error is:

```
XDMP-VALIDATEMISSINGELT: (err:XQDY0027) validate lax { $node } -- Missing required elements: Expected ((any(skip,!())+),(any(skip,!())+)) at fn:doc("d:/xml.xml")/*:note/*:body using schema "/schemas/xsd.xsd"
```

My intention is to have a mandatory occurrence of HTML content inside body like this:

```
<body xml:lang="en"><div></div></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though there is a bug in the MarkLogic schema parsing where a complexType is marked as 'mixed' and also has an extension.

As the first 'mixed' is redundant if you are extending another type which is mixed, this off then everything will work as you expect.

So you should try using the schema:

```xsl
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"    xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"    elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd">
  </xs:import>
  <xs:element name="note">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="body">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
              <xs:extension base="someType">
                <xs:attribute ref="xml:lang" use="required">
                </xs:attribute>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="someType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" processContents="skip"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before digging deeper, I just want to clarify something- Where are your schemas?

MarkLogic wants schemas to live in the schemas database referenced in the configuration of the particular content database. This defaults to the Schemas database.

Have you included all Scemas referenced (via the XML OR the XSD into the Schemas database?)

Look here for details including the order and location for which MarkLogic resolves schemas:  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/schemas

Lastly, when starting to explore schema usage in MarkLogic, please note that it will be a good idea to restart MarkLogic when you change schemas. Technically, you do not need to restart, but really just clear some caches, but if it is OK to restart, then this gets you there faster and keeps the learning curve down a bit.

Comment: yes my xsd is in Schema database. I need to add schema check that pose a mandatory occurrence of html content inside <c:l10n xml:lang="en"><div>some_text</div></c:l10n>, same works in above code, but fails in Marklogic, saying error XDMP-VALIDATEMISSINGELT: (err:XQDY0027) validate lax { $node } -- Missing required elements: Expected (any(skip,!())*,any(skip,!())+).

Comment: I have edited the question for precise info, just check this on free formatter the example with validate, but when I load into marklogic, it doesn't work. --> xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $node := xdmp:document-get("d:/xml.xml")
return
try { xdmp:document-insert("myxml/xml.xml", validate lax { $node } )
    }
catch ($e) { "Validation failed: ",
             $e/error:format-string/text() }